# Solving syntax error, missing operator when transferring XML contents to access table

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-access

Hey I'm transferring the contents of an XML file to access. Now everything works but when I try transferring the data from the "desc" section of each node to the "desc" column in the access table I get this error (transferring all the other aspects of the cards work.):https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eFTz.png

My XML file looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RelPe.png

Would you know any ways to fix the issue? Also I had to avoid parameters because I tried using them and it would only get the contents of the first node (wouldn't cycle), so that's why I'm avoiding it. Here's my code:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim command As OleDbCommand
        ds.ReadXml("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml")
        Dim xmlRoot As XElement = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml").Root

        Try
            conn.Open()
            command = New OleDbCommand()

            Dim cardname As String
            Dim cardtype As String
            Dim carddesc As String
            Dim cardrace As String
            Dim cardimage_url As String
            Dim cardatk As Integer
            Dim carddef As Integer
            Dim cardlevel As Integer

            For Each cards As XElement In xmlRoot.<cards>
                cardname = cards.<name>.Value
                cardtype = cards.<type>.Value
                carddesc = cards.<desc>.Value
                cardrace = cards.<race>.Value
                cardimage_url = cards.<image_url>.Value

                cardatk = cards.<atk>.Value
                carddef = cards.<def>.Value
                cardlevel = cards.<level>.Value
                command.Connection = conn
                command.CommandText = "insert into hello ([name], [type], [desc], [race], [image_url], [atk], [def], [level]) values('" & cardname & "','" & cardtype & "','" & carddesc & "','" & cardrace & "','" & cardimage_url & "','" & cardatk & "','" & carddef & "','" & cardlevel & "')"
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next`
```

Comment: You have embedded quotes in your text around `"Gladiator Beast"`. You need to escape or replace them.

Comment: that occurs for a lot of cards, is there a way around that?

Comment: No. The embedded quotes break the string, so that it's being read as `"some text" some unrelated text "some more text"`, which isn't valid. You're going to have to fix it before you can use it.

Comment: I should clarify that last comment. You can get around it by using parameters, which will properly escape the embedded quotes. You've said you can't use them, but you can. It's hard to tell why they didn't work for you, because you didn't include an effort to use them. You're probably better off deleting this post and writing a new one about how to properly use parameters with the content you're trying to insert instead.

Comment: Parameters probably best approach. However, in VBA I could `Replace(strDesc, Chr(34), " ")`, no idea what VB.net equivalent would be.

Comment: When using parameters it only gets the desc of the first element in the xml

Answer (score 0):

For a long term solution, Ken is right, use parameters.

For an immediate solution, *double* the quotes:

```
Dim text As String
Dim sql As String
Dim quote As String =""""

text = "You have embedded quotes in your text around " + quote + "Gladiator Beast" + quote + "."
sql = text.Replace(quote, quote + quote)
Console.WriteLine(text)
Console.WriteLine(sql)
```

Output:

```
You have embedded quotes in your text around "Gladiator Beast".
You have embedded quotes in your text around ""Gladiator Beast"".
```

Comment: the same with single quotes;)

Comment: Hey I tried this but I still got an error: `final = carddesc.Replace("""", "")`

Comment: Also if I use parameters it only gets the desc from the first element

Comment: Can't be the same error, so please edit your question.